# log4net to MySql JSON data

Tags: mysql, log4net

I am using the MySql appender for log4net

```
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data" />
  <connectionString value="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=logging;Uid=root;Pwd=mysql;" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO log (Date,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception, UserInput) VALUES (?log_date, ?thread, ?log_level, ?logger, ?message, ?exception, ?user_input);" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?message" />
    <dbType value="string" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?user_input" />
    <dbType value="object" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{user_input}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

`user_input` is JSON data that I want to write into my DB, I have a column in MySql that is JSON type and in my code I do the following:

```
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["user_input"] =  new var userInput = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            { "Key", new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "C", "R" },
                { "P", "A" },
                { "Pm", "H" },
                { "Ch", "D" },
                { "Date", DateTime.Now }
            } },
            { "FirstName", "John" },
            { "LastName", "Doe" },
        };
```

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot create a JSON value f rom a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I suggest you trying to change `<dbType value="object" />` for the last param to `<dbType value="string" />`

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest [log4net.Ext.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Ext.Json)? Install the nuget package and try something like:

```
...
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="?user_input" />
    <dbType value="object" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type='log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json'>
        <member value="user_input" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
...
```

Disclosure #1: I haven't tried this. Most probably, you'll need more tweaks as this would produce {"user_input":{...your data...}}

Disclosure #2: I'm the author

Alternatively, you could use the JSON renderer directly as explained in [Log4net stops using custom renderers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045316/log4net-stops-using-custom-renderers). And then use the usual PattenLayout.